# How to move a "div" to certain coordinates using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I would like to know , how to position a div block dynamically to the place where mouse clicks.

I know how to get the value of coordinates of click dynamically.

I want to know how we can move the div block to that coordinate.

I tried the following codes in SO, but nothing is working

```
document.getElementById('someID').style.position='absolute';
document.getElementById('someID').style.left='500px';
document.getElementById('someID').style.top='90px';
```

and the below code

```
var d = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
d.style.position = "absolute";
d.style.left = x_pos;
d.style.top = y_pos;
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it.
Thanks,

Comment: Please post your actual code, including the code that retrieves the mouse coordinates and possibly add a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) to show the issue as the code you posted, setting the styles, works just fine by itself: [**http://jsfiddle.net/5S7ue/**](http://jsfiddle.net/5S7ue/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zNy4C/ something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the units in your position assigning sentence.

To get the mouse position (on click):

```
(function() {
    window.onmousedown = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
        console.log(event.clientX);
        moveDiv(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    }
})();
```

Then send the position to a function to change the position of your div, adding the pixels unit, don't forget it!

```
function moveDiv(x_pos,y_pos){
    var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    d.style.left = x_pos + "px";
    d.style.top = y_pos + "px";
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
(function() {
    window.onmousedown = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
        console.log(event.clientX);
        moveDiv(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    }
})();

function moveDiv(x_pos,y_pos){
    var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    d.style.left = x_pos + "px";
    d.style.top = y_pos + "px";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/cuxemosa/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

try 
`document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(e)})`
you got a mouseevent object where its properties clientX, clientY gives the location of mouse click.
You can then use this to re-position your div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `px` after `d.style.left` and `d.style.top`.

Try this:

```
<style>
#someID {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
}
</style>


<div id="someID">
</div>

<script>

var ele = document.getElementById('someID');
document.onclick = function(e) {    
    ele.style.top = e.offsetY + "px";
    ele.style.left = e.offsetX + "px";
}

</script>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/s99d4/

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');

document.onclick = function(e){  
      a.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
      a.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'
}
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute;    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/yA98r/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple line of Jquery instead of going those complicated routes.

```
$("#divId").hide();


$('body').click(function(event) {
  $("#divId").show().css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
});
```

First you hide the div you want to move (OR don't hide it)

Then move it wherever the user clicks. See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aFACA/35/)

EDIT: Never mind, not all of them look so complicated anymore... Goodluck. :)

Hope this helps.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
d.style.position = "absolute";
d.style.top = "980px"; //or whatever
d.style.left = "970px"; //or whatever
```

Remember that d.style.top is the y-axis and d.style.left is the x-axis.
Therefore,

```
d.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
           d.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
```

Comment: I found this very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full function for this code:

```
document.onmousemove = getCoords;

function getCoords(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var x = e.clientX;
var y = e.clientY;
var div = document.getElementById("MYDIV");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top = y + "px";
div.style.left = x + "px";
}
```